# Surrogate types for serialization in C# Portable Class Library

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, json.net

I am currently porting code to a PCL (Key targets .NET 4.5 + mobile via Xamarin) and am running into a familiar issue, serialization of classes derived from non-serializable dependencies. I am using DataContract/Member attributes with DataContractJsonSerializer and therefore, in the non-portable version of this scenario I used IDataContractSurrogate to effectively swap out classes that couldn't be serailized for custom ones that could. IDataContractSurrogate doesn't exist in PCLs and DataContractJsonSerializer seems to be, logically, a reduced version.

The real question here is:
**What is a portable equivalent of IDataContractSurrogate?**

I have so far looked at:

*[On(De)Serializing] Attributes* that return a surrogate class but don't think this is actually how these attributes work and definitely aren't what they were designed for.

*SerializationBinder* but this doesn't seem to be accepted by the  PCL compatible DataContractJsonSerializer "This functionality is only available when using the BinaryFormatter or the NetDataContractSerializer".

*DataContractResolver* seems like the best option but it isn't included anywhere in the DataContractJsonSerializer settings.

*JsonCreationConverter/[JsonConverter]* from JSON.NET which seem like viable options but would prevent me from swapping serialization formats in future iterations (i.e. JSON is great for debugging but I might want to switch to Binary later, if possible).

Having listed these options out it seems like the issue is that the different .NET serializers have different requirements and therefore their own ways of solving this problem meaning my desire to leave format options open maybe unreasonable. I'm going to look deeper into *DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior* but if there is a less complex alternative I would be more than amenable.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There does not appear to be a PCL version of this, unfortunately.  However, [.NET Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/library) is the next form of PCL, and there appears to be a .NET Standard 1.3 library that contains a `ISerializationSurrogateProvider` interface:

```
public interface ISerializationSurrogateProvider
{
    Type GetSurrogateType(Type type);

    object GetObjectToSerialize(object obj, Type targetType);

    object GetDeserializedObject(object obj, Type targetType);
}
```

This is found in the [`System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives/) package, which can be installed by adding the [`System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml/) package to your [NuGet 3.4+](https://dist.nuget.org/index.html) project.  This package references and includes the `Primitives` package as a dependency.

Additionally, there appears to be another "private" package, [`System.Private.DataContractSerialization`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Private.DataContractSerialization/) which contains a class with two extension methods for the `DataContractSerializer` that modify what appears to be a now-internal property for this class:

```
namespace System.Runtime.Serialization
{
  public static class DataContractSerializerExtensions
  {
    public static ISerializationSurrogateProvider GetSerializationSurrogateProvider(this DataContractSerializer serializer)
    {
      return serializer.SerializationSurrogateProvider;
    }

    public static void SetSerializationSurrogateProvider(this DataContractSerializer serializer, ISerializationSurrogateProvider provider)
    {
      serializer.SerializationSurrogateProvider = provider;
    }
  }
}
```

So, while it does appear PCL support is lacking support for this feature, .NET Standard support exists and should only improve going forward.